# C++ header files for UDP in Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sockets, udp, winsock

I have a linux applications which sends data over UDP protocol. It uses these header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* standard C i/o facilities */
#include <stdlib.h>
/* needed for atoi() */
#include <unistd.h>

/* defines STDIN_FILENO, system calls,etc */
#include <sys/types.h> /* system data type definitions */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket specific definitions */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* INET constants and stuff */
#include <arpa/inet.h> /* IP address conversion stuff */
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h> /* for string and memset etc */
/* gethostbyname */
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
```

I want to make a WIndows version of my app. But some of the above header files do not work in WIndows, especially those for UDP.

Which header files should I substitute them for in Windows (Visual Studio 2010)?

UPDATE:

Ok, so my header now looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
```

I get this error when trying to compile (and many other similar errors):

```
Error   13  error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h  132 1   Client
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At compile-time, you need to use `Winsock2.h` instead of the Unix headers.

At link-time, include `ws2_32.lib` to provide linkage to the required system DLL.

Comment: I have added the WS2_32.lib to Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies and added the #include <winsock2.h> line. Now I get many error swhen I try to compile such as: "Error 13 error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h 132 1 Client"

Comment: Unless it's obvious where the dup is coming from in the error text, you can compile (one of) the module(s) with `/P` to get the preprocessed output and find out where `fd_set` is multiply defined. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Richard - make sure `winsock2.h` precedes `windows.h` if you are including both, per the other answer.  Make sure some other file is not pulling in `windows.h` earlier.  Check in `stdafx.h` and the OpenGL headers.

Answer (score 7):

Comment out the include files that are "missing"
or put them into the following:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#else
// unix includes here
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need most of those includes. The only file you will need is **winsock2.h** and link with **ws2_32.lib**.

So, for all networking stuff, just include **winsock2.h**.

Comment: Or you may prefer ws2tcpip.h, there is a subtle difference with some API calls.

Answer (score 4):

You want to #include winsock2.h.  One peculiarity, you need to #include  *before* including anything else, including :

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
```